# Materialize-css Modal in React with React Router

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, materialize, react-router-v4

Trying to have a modal come in from `Materialize-css` that i get from that npm but nothing is showing up. I am using React with React Router v4 as well

I currently have it set up in my nav bar and the search-bar changes with the #modal1 identifier but the modal doesn't pop up. I would really like to avoid hacky things like have a line or two of jQuery in componentDidMount just for this because if thats the only solution I'll just go back to bootstrap.

I'm trying it with the code straight from the Docs. Please help!

```
<div className='container'> 
        <div id="modalHere" className="modal">
            <div className="modal-content">
                <h4>Modal Header</h4>
                <p>A bunch of text</p>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
                <a href="#!" className="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>   
            <div className="nav-wrapper blue-grey lighten-2">
                <Link to='/professionals' className="brand-logo right"><img src={pegasusIcon} alt='OurTelos logo' className="OurTelosNavbarLogo"/></Link>
                <ul id="nav-mobile" className="left">
                    <li><Link to="/professionals/sessions">Sessions</Link></li>
                    <li><a className="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modalHere">Modal</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

**EDIT**

I added the jquery in my index file for the modal in a `script` tag and my modal does pop up but not properly. Take a look. Also if I use the example with the Fixed-Footer things seem to come out and work just fine.....why

[image: Copied straight from the Docs]

**EDIT 2**

Now I am having an issue that the same modals from a single exported react component will no longer show after the page has been changed by react router...

Comment: Are you initializing this modal? `$('.modal').modal()`

Comment: where exactly would i put that initializing line? also is there a way to achieve this with react and not jQuery?

Comment: You can initialize it on `componentDidMount` lifecycle event. I'm afraid you need `jQuery` in order to use materializecss components. Have you tried material-ui instead?

Comment: I have not but I am interested. I thank you for taking the leap in suggesting this as I do think I will change my project to incorporate this version as its more react friendly.

Comment: @mersocarlin I have updated my answer in accordance with your suggestion

Comment: I'd be nice if you show your JavaScript code as well. It gets easier to help :)

Comment: try this one: https://react-materialize.github.io :)

Comment: Thats where i ended up @Franva. thanks for looking out doe

Comment: @KellysOnTop23 How is the React-Materialize? I tried a few hours and found it's beautiful, but once I got issues, it's hard to solve them. e.g. the Navbar toggle doesn't work.

Comment: @Franva Yeah i've had to deal with a few hacky solutions here and there too. I do like the little details and am almost finished with my project. If I can make it all the way through then I'll recommend it for sure as Im sure it can only get better